# How can I exclude punctuation in "pig latin" function?

Tags: javascript, regex

I apologize if this question has been answered somewhere - please point me in the right direction if so. I have read through a bunch of solutions and have not yet cracked it!

Sooo...basically, I need to:
Move the first letter of each word to the end of it, then add "ay" to the end of the word. Leave punctuation marks untouched.

This is my code so far:

```js
function pigIt(str) {
  var newStr = str.split(" ");

  var changed = newStr.map(function(input) {
    return input.substring(1) + input.charAt(0) + "ay";
  });

  changed = changed.join(" ");
  return changed;
}

console.log(pigIt('Pig latin is cool'));
```

As you can see, the code will work for any input that doesn't include punctuation. Great. Now I need to maybe add a Regex somewhere to exclude punctuation but I don't know where to put it! Please help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split by the word boundary `/(\W+)/` while capturing separator. Transform words only. And then join back.

```js
function pigIt(str) {
  var newStr = str.split(/(\W+)/); // ['Pig', ' ', 'latin', ',- ',..]

  var changed = newStr.map(function(input) {
    if (!/\w/.test(input)) return input // keep non word elements as is
    
    return input.substring(1) + input.charAt(0) + "ay";
  });

  return changed.join("");
}

console.log(pigIt('Pig latin,- is cool!'));
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know you could keep the delimiter by using capture group... though I do now, thanks ;)

Comment: @musefan Me myself found this recently :) Might be helpful to scroll MDN articles down sometimes :) [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split#Splitting_with_a_RegExp_to_include_parts_of_the_separator_in_the_result)

Comment: Yes - exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think because you are going to want to put the punctuation back in the same place after processing, then you will probably be better of doing it all manually.

Loop the input 1 char at a time and build a 'word buffer', every time you hit a non-letter character then process the word buffer and append the non-letter character too.

```js
    function pigIt(str) {
      var process = function(s) {
        if (s.length < 2) {
          return s;
        }
        return s.substring(1) + s.charAt(0) + "ay";
      };
      var result = '';
      var buffer = '';
    
      for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        var c = str[i];
    
        if (c.match(/[a-zA-Z]/i)) {
          buffer += c;
        } else {
          if (buffer.length) {
            result += process(buffer);
            buffer = '';
          }
          result += c;
        }
      }
    
      result += process(buffer);
      buffer = '';
    
      return result;
    }
    
    var output = pigIt('Pig latin is cool.');
    console.log(output);
```